# Struggling in getting output in r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a beginner in shiny app. so first I tried to build an app to calculate distance covered using time taken and speed. I got error as "argument of length zero". Then I entered  `req(input$num_time,input$select_time,input$slider_speed)`this command after that error message is not displaying and also not getting output also.  I'm not able to find where I gone wrong. Please help me in getting the output. I have shown the code I used below:

```
library(shiny)
#library(car)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("terrain model"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("To create a suitable model"),
      br(),
      numericInput("num_time",
                   label = h6("Enter time"),
                   value = 1),
      selectInput("select_time", 
                  label = h6(""),
                  choices = list("Hours"= 1,"Minutes" = 2),
                  selected = "1"),
      
      sliderInput("Speed", 
                  label = "Speed:",
                  min = 2, max = 4.5, value = 2),
      br(),
      actionButton("action",label="Refresh & Calculate")
      ),
    
    
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("text_distance")
    )
  )
 )


server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  #calculate distance travelled
  observe({input$action_Calc
    values$int <- isolate({ input$num_time * recode(input$select_time,"1='60';2='1'")*input$slider_speed
      })
    })
  #Display values entered
  
  output$text_distance <- renderText({
    req(input$num_time,input$select_time,input$slider_speed)
    if(input$action_Calc==0)""
    else
    paste("Distance:", round(values$int,0))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find any use of "Refresh & Calculate" button since the calculation is performed as soon as any of the input changes.

You can try this code :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("terrain model"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("To create a suitable model"),
      br(),
      numericInput("num_time",
                   label = h6("Enter time"),
                   value = 1),
      selectInput("select_time", 
                  label = h6(""),
                  choices = list("Hours"= 1,"Minutes" = 2),
                  selected = "1"),
      
      sliderInput("Speed", 
                  label = "Speed:",
                  min = 2, max = 4.5, value = 2),
      br(),
      actionButton("action",label="Refresh & Calculate")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text_distance")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  #Display values entered
  output$text_distance <- renderText({
    val <- input$num_time/dplyr::recode(input$select_time,"1"=1,"2"=60)*input$Speed * 1000
    paste("Distance:", round(val,0), 'meters')
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please check my answer that I have posted whats wrong

Comment: What is the formula that you are using to calculate the answer? See the updated answer if it is closer to what you want. BTW, you should not post that as an answer since it is not an answer. You can comment under my post or edit the question instead.

Comment: ok sorry for as answer....The updated answer is working.